# Padding in nested structs

Tags: c, memory, struct, padding, unions

On my machine the program attached below prints 1,2,3,4. Is this the expected behavior in general, or can the padding of

```
struct {
    Vector position;
    Vector velocity;
    Vector acceleration;
};
```

be different from the padding of

```
struct {
    double x;
    double y;
    double dxdt;
    double dydt;
};
```

due to the nesting of structs? In general, does a struct where all members have the same type:

```
struct {
 Type member1;
 Type member2;
 ... 
 Type memberN;
}
```

have the same memory layout as a nested struct

```
struct {
 struct group1 { 
    Type member1;
    Type member2;
    ...
    Type memberI};
 };
 struct group2 { 
    Type memberIplus1;
    Type memberIplus2;
    ...
    Type memberIplusJ};
 };
 ...
 struct groupM {
    ...
    Type memberN
 };
}
```

Attached program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct vector {
    double x;
    double y;
} Vector;

typedef union {
    struct {
        Vector position;
        Vector velocity;
        Vector acceleration;
    };
    struct {
        double x;
        double y;
        double dxdt;
        double dydt;
    };
} State;


int main() {
 State state = {
    .position = {1,2},
    .velocity = {3,4},
 };
 printf("%0.f\n",state.x);
 printf("%0.f\n",state.y);
 printf("%0.f\n",state.dxdt);
 printf("%0.f\n",state.dydt);
 return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ordinary C implementations will not insert any padding in homogeneous structures (structures that contain only members of a single type, including arrays, unions, and structures whose direct or indirect members are only of that type). The C standard permits it, but, since homogeneous structures have no need for padding for alignment, the only reason I am aware of for inserting padding would be a debugging feature to “fuzz” the program (attempting to trigger misbehavior due to relying on assumptions not guaranteed by the C standard).

Then, since accessing a `union` member other than the last one stored reinterprets the memory as the new type, accessing `state.x` will get the data stored for `state.position.x`, and similarly for the other members.

Comment: Thank you! Does this imply that an homogenoues array can in most cases be cast to an array with with the same datatype? For example, struct {double a; double b; double c;} can be cast to an array double array[3]? What is the definition of homogeneous?

Comment: @Angelos: Re “Does this imply that an homogenoues array can in most cases be cast to an array with with the same datatype?”: No. First, my answer speaks to reinterpreting a homogeneous structure, not about reinterpreting a homogeneous array. Second, in most circumstances, reinterpreting any structure as another type will not have behavior defined by the C standard due to the aliasing rules in C 2018 6.5 7. It works in the situation addressed in this answer because it is contained in a union, and, in C, using a union member other than the last one stored reinterprets the memory as the new type.

Comment: @Angelos: “Homogeneous” is not used in the C standard and does not have a particular technical definition. It is an ordinary English word I used in its ordinary sense, to describe structures that contain only members of a single type.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is permitted by the clause regarding union members that share a common initial sequence, C11 [6.5.2.3 paragraph 6](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3p6)

> One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: if a union contains several structures that share a common initial sequence (see below), and if the union object currently contains one of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them anywhere that a declaration of the completed type of the union is visible. Two structures share a common initial sequence if corresponding members have compatible types (and, for bit-fields, the same widths) for a sequence of one or more initial members.

Since both structures begin with 4 `double` members, that's a "common initial sequence", So you can store into one of those members and then read from the corresponding member of the other one.

Comment: If this were a valid interpretation of “common initial sequence”, then `struct { double a; char b; char c; }` and `struct { struct { double a; char b; }; char c; }` would have `c` at the same place, but typical C implementations put the first `c` at offset 9 and the second at offset 16, since its `struct { double a; char b; }` has seven bytes of padding to make its size a multiple of the eight-byte alignment required for `double`. The common initial sequence can apply only to direct members.